# Header and footer width is not enough in iOS

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer, ios

In iOS header and footer width slightly doesn’t reach the right edge of the page:

> [image: header]

> [image: footer]

Tested in Chrome/Firefox/Safari on iOS 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fixed now:

> [image: top]

> [image: bottom]