# Grey area for image upload popup is less than it should be

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, uploader, ios

When upload an image popup is showed the dark grey background area behind the popup doesn’t propagated to the entire page. Right side is reduced:

> [image]

This issue is probably related to another one: [Header and footer width is not enough in iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308487/339911)

iOS 11.2.6 iPad Pro 10.5”

Comment: @Glorfindel did you see the red circle?

Comment: @Glorfindel Totally different problem. Not a duplicate.

Comment: ah, wrong gray area ...

Comment: @SonicWizard he just probably overlooked due to my bad explanation and wording. If you can improve this question please do it.

Comment: It looks good as is.

Comment: @Glorfindel 50 shades of grey uploader area :)

Comment: No repro. Please specify browser and OS. (tag iOS isn't enough, what device? Why not using mobile theme?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard device screen size is enough to use full site version

Comment: Size is not relevant, thing is using the full site theme on mobile device. Since it was never meant this way, design problems are totally expected

Comment: @ShadowWizard don’t use full site on mobile device, don’t use mobile site on desktop device... pfff... it’s possible to make site less dependent on device, but you will always consider such and other things “too minor to implement”.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Would you suggest using the full or mobile site on a Microsoft Surface RT?

Comment: Never said "don't use", I mean that if using things in a way they were not meant to be used, problems are expected.

Comment: @SonicWizard if it is considered a mobile device then mobile site theme. Otherwise, full site theme.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The thing I was trying to point out was, there is no concrete distinction between devices considered a "mobile" device and a "non-mobile" device.

Comment: @SonicWizard maybe, but SE can't possibly test and support all possible devices in their design. I believe the upcoming responsive design will solve most of those problems.

Comment: This has been hapenning for the last 4 years for sure and I was always lazy to report :)

Comment: @nicael but now you can upvote this report which is impossible for own posts.

Comment: @alex indeed!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fixed now, but iOS version is slightly newer than it was. 11.4.1:

> [image: no white at the right side]